# Javascript/JQuery how to validate phone number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

How to validate input field to enter mobile number and that mobile number should **begins with "07"** also if some one enter mobile number with space, **space should remove on click.** . eg: 07 xxxx xxxx onclick it should be 07xxxxxxxx

Now i used html 5 validation method to give warning:

```
<input  type="text" name="mobile_number" required="" title="Number format should be 07xxxxxxxx" pattern="\d{10}">
```

but this code does not validate it. can someone help me to validate this

Comment: You can use jquery "Validation" framework to solve your purpose. You can specify your different conditions and the corresponding error message using this. Whatever check remains, you can do that using your javascript code.

Comment: @user3099298 I know how to do it via javascript but not using HTML5 if you want that code I can give it to you.

Comment: @TruePS if you could please give me that code, thank you

Comment: @user3099298 It is difficult to remove spaces but you could add validation if user enter spaces between numbers you could pop an alert box for that.I am able to check whether the number starts from 07 as well as I am able to check spaces between numbers but I am little confused how to remove those spaces.So i suggest you could use validation if users enter spaces between numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked me to do it using simple javascript.Here is you answer

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
  <body>



  <script>
 function myFunction()
 {
  var xyz=document.getElementById('mob_no').value.trim();

  if(xyz.substr(0,2)==='07')
  {

 var new_no= document.getElementById('mob_no').value.replace(/\s/g,"")
 alert("number after validations check is"+new_no);
 }
else
  {
alert("incorrect number");
 }
  }
```

```
 <input  type="text" id="mob_no" name="mobile_number" required="" title="Number format should be 07xxxxxxxx" onblur="myFunction()">
  </body>
 </html>
```

Feel free to ask anything and plz repond it worked or not.

Answer (score 3):

When I had to solve the same problem, I used Masked Input Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern for accepting telephone number starting with 07 is

```
<input  type="text" name="mobile_number" required="" title="Number format should be 07xxxxxxxx" pattern="^07\d{8}$">
```

validate `07` at the beginning and after that accept any 8 digit like follow

```
pattern="^07\d{8}$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Niles has the right idea.

So, just attach a click handler or a behavior that strips the spaces... ala.

```
var a = "07989   8989 8 8"; 
//substitute your element reference ala jQuery('input[name="mobile_number"]');
a = a.replace(/\s+/g,''); // strip the white space

if( /^07\d{8}$/.test(a) ){
  // passed test
}else{
  // did not pass, show error
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe, like Niles said you would want to use the pattern `pattern="^07\d{8}$"` which means, in english `String starting with "07" ending with any numerical sequence equaling 8 characters`

Further more, like James was pointing out, use Javascript to remove your whitespaces. However I would add a interval, to clear them automatically so the user understands how the input works for further usage.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var inputElm = document.getElementById('phone_number_id_name'), // id="" name of element
        input = inputElm.value; 
    setInterval(function() { inputElm.value = input.replace(/\s+/g, ''); }, 100); // turncate white-space of input every 100ms
</script>
```